# Setting up a grid to carousel?

Tags: 8, media

Alright everyone, I'm sure this is a relatively simple thing, but I'm on the verge of tearing my hair out.

What I'm trying to accomplish is setting up images to appear in a grid, that when clicked pulls up a gallery/carousel, allowing you to scroll through the images there as well.

I've downloaded the slick modules, and correct dependencies. I also have bootstrap correctly set up as well. Honestly if you have an alternative your prefer more, please let me know.

https://www.drupal.org/project/slick
-https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/
-https://github.com/gdsmith/jquery.easing
https://www.drupal.org/project/slick_media
https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity_image
https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field
https://www.drupal.org/project/blazy

Drupal 8

Comment: please tag 7 or 8 and make links to modules involved.

Comment: The post has been updated with the correct information.

Comment: any error in browser console? any log?

Comment: I just have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the [Lightgallery module](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightgallery) which is available for Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 also. It integrates the [lightGallery jquery plugin](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/) into Drupal. This is compatible with Views and it also provides an image field formatter.

You can see demos for the lightGallery jquery plugin [here](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/).

Comment: This was a massive pain to install, so in case anyone else has difficulties getting this to work via composer follow the instructions at the bottom. https://www.drupal.org/project/lightgallery/issues/2779141

Answer (score 0):

I almost always use Slick for carousels, but it sounds like you're maybe asking for the image to pop up in a modal window.

For Drupal 8, the Colorbox module is good for that.

https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox

You can use it for image fields or views.

Edited to add: Here's a tutorial!

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-8-responsive-colorbox-gallery-with-caption-text/